# linking of an assembly out fails because of libSystem.dylib

Tags: macos, assembly

I'm writing some very basic assembly programs for study purposes. I'm on a Macbook with Intel Core i7 and Big Sur Installed.

Consider the following:

```
.data #start data segment

x:
        .long   1
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   38

sum:
        .long   0

.text   #start of code segment

.globl _start
_start:
        movl    $4, %eax # EAX will serve as a number of elements remained
        mov     $0, %ebx # EBX will store the sum
        mov     $x, %ecx # ECX will point to the current element to be summed

top:    addl    (%ecx), %ebx
        dec     %eax
        jnz     top
        addl    $4, %ecx

done:   movl    %ebx, sum(%rip) #result in sum :)
```

if I compile it:

```
as sum.s -g -o sum.o
```

it works, but the linking phase complains:

```
ld -e _start sum.o -o sum                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ~/D/test
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
```

How could I fix this? Why does it need that in this specific case?

If an easy solution was using x86_32, I'd be more than happy with it, but I don't know how to tell it to assemble and link like that.

Comment: You don’t have a main... do you want a program or a library

Comment: I do! It's called `_start` and it's explicitly defined via the `-e` flag :).
I'm trying to write a program. Actually I'll use it just along with the debugger, for study purposes

Comment: Sorry didn’t read the man page, I assume it still has to have the same sig as main, you can’t just say that particular registers mean things... it would be easier to make a normal main in C and call start(x,y)... I have an example like that if you want me to dig it up.